# Xcode storyboard compile error, stringsfiles.doesn't exist

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I cannot compile my storyboard, it always said "Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach....". It also said that "The folder stringsfiles.plist does not exist".

Any one knows how to fix this? Error message is as below pic.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdt4M.png)

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project and do a full rebuild?

Comment: yes, i have tried that, doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 2):

Might be it's because of the internal error while compiling.

You may follow few steps.

1. Remove all your derived data from Xcode.
2. Do deep clean and rebuild the project. (Command + option + shift + k)

if doesn't work then try below option.

it might work to create a new storyboard file & move everything into the new file from the older storyboard file.

remove older file and rebuild it again.

Hope it work for you!

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by deleting my latest changes in the storyboard, until I had a version without this error.

In my case the error was related to an incorrect segue. So just deleting your latest segue edits might work.